# include self relation data in query in django

Tags: python, django

i have comment model and i want to include all child comment in list query.
in this modal a comment can have parent comment

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    parentId = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

i want to list comments which should include parent commnet data

expected array

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    body:"anything",
    parentId:{
         id:34,
         body:"second"
       }
  },
  {
   //second
  }
]
```

my query was this
not working

```
        query = Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(
            parent_comment=Comment.objects.filter(
                id=OuterRef('parentId')) if F('parentId') else "None",
        ).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your precise use case could help but from what i understand there is two possibilties.

Either you really want (or do not mind) a list of dict. In that case you want to take a look at DRF Serializers
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

```
class CommentParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    body = serializers.CharField()

class CommentSerializer(CommentParentSerializer):
    parentId = CommentParentSerializer()
```

Calling `CommentSerializer(Comment.objects.all(), many=True).data` will yield the anwser.

However I'm afraid that's not what you asked since this will destroy the QuerySet and yield a List.

`Comment.objects.select_related("parentId")` will essentially give you access to the parent of any comment ex: `my_comment.parentId.body`.